# Accessing ViewData in Layout for page with partial view not working

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

From a partial view, I want to include scripts or styles and have them rendered into the header or footer (instead of inline) so I have a taghelper and htmlextension that works when I used TempData in the htmlextensions, but if I use ViewData, it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

**Partial view:**

```
<style asp-resource-location="Header">
    .partial1 {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>

<h2>Test Partial</h2>

<script asp-resource-location="Footer">
    alert("Partial1");
</script>
```

**Htmlextensions:**

```
public static IHtmlContent InlineScripts(this IHtmlHelper html, Enums.ResourceLocation location)
{
    var result = new StringBuilder();
    var scripts = html.ViewData.ContainsKey(location.ToString()) ? html.ViewData[location.ToString()] as List<string> : new List<string>();
    foreach (var script in scripts)
    {
        result.Append(script);
    }

    var tag = new TagBuilder(location == Enums.ResourceLocation.Header ? "style" : "script");
    tag.InnerHtml.SetHtmlContent(result.ToString());

    return tag;
}

public static void AddInlineScriptParts(this IHtmlHelper html, Enums.ResourceLocation location, string script)
{
    var scripts = html.ViewData.ContainsKey(location.ToString()) ? html.ViewData[location.ToString()] as List<string> : new List<string>();
    scripts.Add(script);
    html.ViewData[location.ToString()] = scripts;
}
```

**Layout page:**

```
@Html.InlineScripts(Enums.ResourceLocation.Header)
```

**Style Taghelper:**

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    if (Location != Enums.ResourceLocation.Header)
        return;

    var viewContextAware = _htmlHelper as IViewContextAware;
    viewContextAware?.Contextualize(ViewContext);

    var style = output.GetChildContentAsync().Result.GetContent();

    _htmlHelper.AddInlineScriptParts(Location, style);

    output.SuppressOutput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used ViewContext.HttpContext.Items and it works. I figured it would be better to use than TempData which uses session. If anyone has any reason why I shouldn't use this, please let me know. And if anyone knows why ViewData doesn't work, I would be interested to know also.